# ASP.NET Core 2.1 How to call filter that refers to a class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have this action filter that I want to call from a function. However, within this filter I am referring to another class called ValidateRoleClient. How can I do a service injection? Or call this class in my function properly?

```
public class RolesFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public ValidateRoleClient validateRoleClient;
    public string Role { get; set; }

    public RolesFilterAttribute(ValidateRoleClient validateRoleClient)
    {
        this.validateRoleClient = validateRoleClient;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (context.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["Token"] != null || context.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["RefreshToken"] != null)
        {
            TokenViewModel tvm = new TokenViewModel
            {
                Token = context.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["Token"],
                RefreshToken = context.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["RefreshToken"]
            };
            ValidateRoleViewModel vrvm = new ValidateRoleViewModel
            {
                Role = Role,
                Token = tvm
            };
            validateRoleClient.ValidateRole(vrvm);
        }
    }
}
```

This is how I refer to the filter in my function

```
[RolesFilter]
public IActionResult About()
{
    return View();
}
```

The current error I get from this is

> Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression
>   State Error   CS7036  There is no argument given that corresponds to
>   the required formal parameter 'validateRoleClient' of
>   'RolesFilterAttribute.RolesFilterAttribute(ValidateRoleClient)'

Comment: It's probably a bit much to implement your own filter-factory for this - There are simpler options in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.1#dependency-injection), e.g. with `TypeFilterAttribute`.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your attribute inside a `FilterFactory` like so:

```
public class RolesFilterAttribute : Attribute, IFilterFactory
{
    public string Role { get; set; }       

    public IFilterMetadata CreateInstance(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return new RolesFilterAttributeImplementation(
            serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ValidateRoleClient>(),
            Role
        );
    }

    private class RolesFilterAttributeImplementation : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        private readonly ValidateRoleClient validateRoleClient;
        private readonly string role;

        public RolesFilterAttributeImplementation(ValidateRoleClient validateRoleClient, string role)
        {
            this.validateRoleClient = validateRoleClient;
            this.role = role;
        }

        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            if (context.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["Token"] != null || context.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["RefreshToken"] != null)
            {
                TokenViewModel tvm = new TokenViewModel
                {
                    Token = context.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["Token"],
                    RefreshToken = context.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["RefreshToken"]
                };
                ValidateRoleViewModel vrvm = new ValidateRoleViewModel
                {
                    Role = role,
                    Token = tvm
                };
                validateRoleClient.ValidateRole(vrvm);
            }
        }
    }

    public bool IsReusable => false;
}
```

Of course the `ValidateRoleClient` service must first be configured to be injected.

You can then use the `RolesFilterAttribute` attribute as you normally would.

And you can read more about `IFilterFactory` here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.1#ifilterfactory

Comment: Hello! Thanks for answering. What is the IsReusable for?